# Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I use a script to upload images.

in the script i want to create thumbnails.

First i make a copy, after the copy i want to resize the copy.

I have

```
$originalfile =//the file i just uploaded

$kopiefile = //the copy destination /same filename as original but with an extra dir added.

if (!copy($originalfile, $kopiefile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $originalfile...\n";
} else {
    $kopiefile = "http://mydomain.com/media/img/thumbs/".$file_name;
    echo $kopiefile;
    $kopiefile -> resize(300, 0, false);
}
```

the copy file works i can see the newly created file.

The echo $kopiefile gives me a link directly to the image wich works if i copy the link.

but now i get to the

```
$kopiefile -> resize(300, 0, false);
```

part and i get the error

Fatal error: Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in .... line 176

where line 176 is

```
$kopiefile -> resize(300, 0, false);
```

what is wrong with my code?

i also tryd to use:

$kopiefile = "/home/censored/domains/censored/public_html/ve/media/img/thumbs/".$file_name;

but it isnt working.

Can someone plz help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$kopiefile` is just a string, and not an object, and therefore cannot have member functions like `$someobject->resize()`.

You have to load the picture into an object which has some kind of resize method. What you're doing now is putting the url of the file in a string variable.

Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Or this: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/
Scroll to the bottom for the SimpleImage class code.
Use it like this:

```
<?php
   include('SimpleImage.php');
   $image = new SimpleImage();
   $image->load('picture.jpg');
   $image->resizeToWidth(250);
   $image->save('picture2.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: What is the easyest way cause i really liked the simple ide of  resize(300, 0, false);  imagecopyresized looks like it needs extra codeing for keeping the ratio of the image right.

Comment: You can use -> 'tends to' operator only to access members in a class and here I don't see it is used that way. Probably you may want to check that out.

Comment: Is there no other way, i really dont like adding classes i want to keep everything as simple as possible. I dont want to add 105 rules of code when it is not necesery.

Comment: I dont know of any built in functionality other than the GD library (the one that provides the imagecopyresized() function). You could use that but as you said it's not fully tailored for your requirements, so unfortunately i think its unavoidable to add some code.

Comment: Ok i saved the SimpleImage.php class and added the code:  $kopiefile = "http://mydomain/media/img/thumbs/".$file_name;
      echo $kopiefile;
      include('SimpleImage.php');
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load($originalfile);
      $image->resizeToWidth(250);
      $image->save($kopiefile); but now i get error Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'mydomain.com/media/img/thumbs/13648963700veersel.PNG' for writing: No such file or directory in...  but the image is there if i copy the url wich dosnt exist. I used relativepath to the img and now it works thx

Comment: i think that means that saving the image failed because the folder doesnt exist, are you sure the path is correct? try saving it in current directory (just $image->save("here.jpg")) to see if the path was the problem.
EDIT: ok good no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using `simpleimage` php library. You have to load the image frist `$image = SimpleImage('path.jpg');` then `$image->resize()` will works. First download simple image and then try it

download it here: [simpleimage](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143)

Answer (score 0):

$kopiefile is not **object** and has no method **resize**.

Try to use https://code.google.com/p/ag-php-classes/wiki/ImagesHelper class =)